# Use AAD to create roles for users

Tags: azure-active-directory

I want to create a new tenant
And then add users to the tenant
Users will have specific roles  example: SupportAgent.

Does this require AD premium ? Any links to setting this up?
Thank you so much for helping us.
Peter

Answer (score 0):

You do not need AAD Premium to gain access to create custom directory roles.

You can learn how to create custom roles here:

[Create custom roles in Azure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/custom-roles)

> If the built-in roles don't meet your specific access needs, you can
>   create your own custom roles. Just like built-in roles, you can assign
>   custom roles to users, groups, and service principals at subscription,
>   resource group, and resource scopes. Custom roles are stored in an
>   Azure Active Directory (Azure AD) tenant and can be shared across
>   subscriptions. Each tenant can have up to 2000 custom roles. Custom
>   roles can be created using Azure PowerShell, Azure CLI, or the REST
>   API.

You can learn more about role-based access control in Azure Active Directory here:

[What is role-based access control (RBAC)?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/overview)